# Pull 2 different custom post type with 2 different WordPress into external website

Tags: custom-post-types

I have two different WordPress pages while the main site was developed under Laravel framework. Both WordPress sub-sites have different approach for the main site. It happens that the sub-site #1 was hooked to the main site and it display properly all the blog posts/custom posts. But when I tried to hooked the sub-site #2 to the main site, it still carry the posts of sub-site #1 and/or whenever I tried to set the `"post_type" => "page_customs"` it don't display the custom post I have there.

Here's the code i have for sub-site #1:

```
<?php require('site1/wp-load.php');
global $post;

$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
rsort( $sticky );
$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 5 );
$args = array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'order' => 'DESC' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($query->have_posts()) : 
  while ($query->have_posts()) : 
    $query->the_post();

    $field = get_field_object('article_sticky_post');
    $value = $field['value'];
    $choices = $field['choices'];

    if ($value) :
        foreach ( $value as $v ) :
            $set = $v;
        endforeach;

      if($set == 'yes'): ?>

      <div class="listed-type-item _hide">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> | <span class="text-success small">Read more...</span></a>
      </div>

      <?php endif; // $set
    endif; // $value
  endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

While here's the code for sub-site #2:

```
<?php require('site2/wp-load.php');
global $post;

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'nas_customs', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'DESC' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($query->have_posts()) :
  while ($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="listed-type-item _hide">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> | <span class="text-success small">Read more...</span></a>
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And it happens that the sub-site #1 content (page title) loads on sub-site #2.

Comment: Can you indent/format your code? It's difficult to read :(

Comment: Sorry about that, there I reformat the codes.

Comment: hmmm where are these files, what are they named, and how are they loaded? You're sure that only one is ever loaded at an time? Never both?

Comment: both site1 & site2 wp folders are sub-folders of my laravel main site. site1 display various news and related blog posts, while site2, display investment pages relatively to the main site. though, I realized site2 was previously declared as sub-domain, could it be that the issue?

Comment: No, but can you be more specific, is there ever a point when both files are loaded? Are those standalone files? Have you tested the WP installs themselves as WP installs ignoring these scripts and the Laravel stuff? Again, you can `require('site1/wp-load.php')` or `require('site2/wp-load.php')` but not both in the same request